# Coordinatable continuous functions in terms of orthogonal systems $\{e^{in\theta}\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Question. Let $f$ be an arbitrary  $2\pi$-periodic integrable function on reals. Does there exists any sequence $\{t_n\}$  with $f(\theta)=\sum t_ne^{in\theta}$?

If NOT, what about if we replace integrable function with a continuous one?!

Comment: Your second part does not make sense. If the result is not true for continuous fucntions it cannot be true for integrable functions.

Comment: you need more for pointwise convergence, say Holder regularity. If you assume $f$ is $L^2$ then you have convergence of the series in $L^2$.

Comment: @ Calvin Khor: Any counterexample?

Comment: Yes, there is a classical "construction" that uses the Uniform Boundedness Principle. In fact I recently asked a question about this construction here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406915/what-is-the-baire-category-argument-here-divergence-of-many-fourier-series-at

Comment: @Calvin Khor: It seems you assume that $f(\theta)=\sum t_ne^{in\theta}$ implies $\hat{f}(n)=t_n$!!  Why?

Comment: well to finish that to full rigour, you're going to need to define that equal sign very very precisely. That is, what do you mean when you say
$$ f(\theta)=\sum t_ne^{in\theta}$$

Comment: I mean that does there exists a   sequence $\{t_n\}$ such that  $f$ is represented by $f(\theta)=\sum t_ne^{in\theta}$  **pointwisely**?

Comment: Could you please write more about why pointwise convergence of the series  $\sum t_ne^{in\theta}$ implies   uniform convergence?

Comment: I don't know if its true and i shouldn't comment while busy, sorry

Comment: It is clear you are asking a more subtle question that involves the uniqueness of the trigonometric series representing a function, and are not asking a basic question on Fourier series, especially since you already know about the book of Katznelson. Please edit the question to make this more clear for other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following theorem of de la Vallée-Poussin, which I quote from page 880 of J. Marshall Ash's [Uniqueness of Representation by Trigonometric Series](https://math.depaul.edu/mash/monthly_uniqueness.pdf):

> If $S=\sum_n t_n e^{inx}$ converges to $f$ at each $x$,  and if $f$ is finite at each $x$ and if $\int_{\mathbb T} |f(x)| dx< \infty$, then $S$ is the Fourier series of $f$.

This theorem is to be found in Zygmund's Trigonometric Series, Vol I, page 326. The beginning of Ash's paper proves the special case for $f=0$, but it seems that the proof of the general case spans several pages, so I will leave it at that.

For your question: consider a continuous function $f$ constructed via the Uniform Boundedness Principle (see for example, the note of Paul Garrett linked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406915/what-is-the-baire-category-argument-here-divergence-of-many-fourier-series-at)). Suppose that $S$ converged pointwise to $f$. By de la Vallée-Poussin's theorem, $S$ must be the Fourier series of $f$. But the Fourier series of $f$ does not converge at every point, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day
. It was perfectly  brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $\{t_n|n\in\Bbb Z\}$ exists for which $f$ satisfies the identity$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}t_ne^{in\theta},$$applying $g\mapsto\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$ gives $\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta=2\pi t_k$, since in terms of the Kronecker delta $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(n-k)\theta}d\theta=2\pi\delta_{nk}$ for integers $n,\,k$. In other words, if a solution exists it is$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta^\prime)e^{-in\theta^\prime}d\theta^\prime\right)e^{in\theta}.$$If such an $f$ is modified at countably many values of $\theta$, the integrals in the second display-line equation are unchanged, so the function obtained from such a sum is the "original" function. Then the display-line equations are each true of the "new" $f$, except at countably many points.

Comment: Seems you assume $\int( \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}t_ne^{in\theta})e^{ik\theta}=\sum_{\in \mathbb{Z}}\int t_ne^{in\theta}e^{ik\theta}$? Why can the infinite sum and integration be interchanged? We only have the point-wise convergent.